# Apache maven plugin upgrade

Tags: maven, ubuntu, plugins

I've seen here (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJARSIGNER-17) that the **Maven Jar Signer Plugin** has a new version which solves the proxy issue.

In Ubuntu 14.04, I have Maven installed

```
> uname -a
Linux jenkins 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

My pom.xml is here: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV-Snooper

How can I tell to MAVEN to download the latest version of the plugin and using it?

Thanks!
Riccardo

** EDIT: moved to Maven 3.3.9 ***

** Edit: my pom.xml **

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
            ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, (my personal recommendation) -- consider upgrading to the latest Maven (3.3.9).

Secondly, the answer to your question: in your `pom.xml` (or respective parent `pom.xml`) define the version of the `maven-jar-plugin`:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                ...
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks, maven-jar-plugin is already on 2.6 and maven-jarsigner-plugin is on 1.4. How can install the version provided in the link here https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins

Comment: I moved (using https://launchpad.net/~andrei-pozolotin/+archive/ubuntu/maven3) to 3.3.9. The problem still remains

Comment: The one from your link is the latest `SNAPSHOT` which is probably unstable yet. In order to use that one, you'll need to build it from source and install it in your local repository. (You should be able to do this by checking out the project and running something along the lines of `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install -DskipTests`).

Comment: Do you think that if I wait 1 month, this feature will be available on andrej ppa?

Comment: Log in to launchapd and contact Andrei Pozolotin and also drop an e-mail to the Maven Developers' List (dev@maven.apache.org) and you'll surely find that out.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me!

Comment: Glad to be of help! :)